# I can't append to an existing form using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, append

I have a form that originally I decided to wrap using a div:

```
<div class="formWrap">
 <input class="desc" name="newdescription[]" value="" />
</div>
```

And I add some fields dynamically:

```
newDesc = $('.desc:first').clone();
$(newDesc).appendTo('.formWrap');
```

Up to here, everything was working like a charm, but later I changed my mind and decided to make it a form as I won't be using AJAX anymore but instead I'll have the form submit to a next page.

```
<form class="formWrap" type="post" action="nextpage.php">
 <!-- Some inputs -->
</form >
```

As soon as I changed the div into a form, I couldn't append anymore, if I put it back to a div it works.

A solution that I found was leaving the div and wrap everything into a form. But even if it is a solution I am still curious as for why I can't get it to work directly with a form.

```
   <form type="post" action="nextpage.php">
   <div class="formWrap">
         <!-- Some inputs -->
   </div>
   </form >
```

I've been reading and I don't find any restrictions as to not being able to append to a form, so I am a bit lost now. Any Ideas?

Comment: Works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/uaeh1kjr/

Comment: Try `$('<input name="newdescription[]" value="" />').appendTo('.formWrap');`

Comment: I know! It is crazy, I must be missing something, but I swear the only thing I do in my code is changing the div for a form and it stops working. :(

Comment: Another way is to append to form.
    $('.formWrap').append('<input name="newdescription[]" value="" />')
All this works.

Comment: I changed my code to the actual code in case it changes anything, I am cloning the input, but the issue is the same, changing the div for an input breaks it.

Comment: I tried append() and is the same issue.

Comment: Please click the `<>` an create a [mcve] with HTML that shows the issue

Comment: @mplungjan I will try to reproduce the error here. That might help me get the answer. so far adding a wrapper fixed it.thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody gets the same error, this might help.
It took a while to find the answer, but I found the error. I realized that the form was inside a form, obviously a huge error! 
I guess Jquery prevents from appending into a form that is inside another form.

```
<form>
.
.
.
<form class="formWrap" type="post" action="nextpage.php">
 <!-- Some inputs -->
</form >
.
.
.
</form >
```

If you can't append into a form, most probably it is a child of another form.
Here is a fiddle showing how it doesn't work:

https://jsfiddle.net/uaeh1kjr/1/

And as @Eddie mentioned in his comment, this one works, with only one form: https://jsfiddle.net/uaeh1kjr/